# Django template with javascript rendering problem

Tags: javascript, django, templates

I ran into a problem when my template contains some javascript. For instance

```
<script>var i = /{{([a-z]*)}}/gi;</script>
```

Sure enough the template interpreter wants to interpret everything that is in double curled braces {{}} as a variable. Now I wonder if there is a way to turn off such a behavior similar to 
`{% autoescape off %}{% endautoescape %}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use built-in tags: {% verbatim %} and {% endverbatim %} like this:

```
{% verbatim %}
     <script>var i = /{{([a-z]*)}}/gi;</script>
{% endverbatim %}
```